# MouseListener stopping

Tags: java, mouselistener

I am making a simple 2048 clone in java, just for fun, but I'm having a problem. After the board fills up, MouseListener seems to stop listening. For now, that isn't a problem, but part of the 2048 game is that you can move if you have tiles you can combine even when all tiles are full, so it will become a problem later in development.

Expected output: A 2 is shown on the screen. Every time you click, one more 2 will show up, until the board is full. When you click the top of the screen, the top left tile will become "1", and when you click the bottom, it becomes "2", left is "3", and right is "4". Once the board fills up, I expect it to continue "listening" and keep changing that top left tile to the corresponding numbers.

Real output: All of the above, except that once all the tiles are full, the top left corner will not change values.

How do I make it so that the MouseListener does not stop listening?

The following is my code.

```
package a2048;

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{
    int randx, randy, quit;
    int a1, a2, a3, a4, b1, b2, b3 ,b4, c1, c2, c3, c4, d1, d2, d3, d4;

    int GetRandom(int min, int max)
    {
       int range = (max - min) + 1;  
       double rand = (Math.random() * range) + min;
       return (int) rand;
    }

    void RandomSpawn()
    {
        int numcheck;

        numcheck = 0;       
        quit = 0;

        while(quit == 0)
        {
            while(numcheck == 0)
            {
                randx = GetRandom(1, 4);
                randy = GetRandom(1, 4);

                if(randx == 1)
                {
                    if(randy == 1 && a1 == 0)
                    {
                        a1 = 2;
                        numcheck = 1;
                    }
                    else if(randy == 2 && a2 == 0)
                    {
                        a2 = 2;
                        numcheck = 1;
                    }
                    else if(randy == 3 && a3 == 0)
                    {
                        a3 = 2;
                        numcheck = 1;
                    }
                    else if(randy == 4 && a4 == 0)
                    {
                        a4 = 2;
                        numcheck = 1;
                    }
                }

                else if(randx == 2)
                {
                    if(randy == 1 && b1 == 0)
                    {
                        b1 = 2;
                        numcheck = 1;
                    }
                    else if(randy == 2 && b2 == 0)
                    {
                        b2 = 2;
                        numcheck = 1;
                    }
                    else if(randy == 3 && b3 == 0)
                    {
                        b3 = 2;
                        numcheck = 1;
                    }
                    else if(randy == 4 && b4 == 0)
                    {
                        b4 = 2;
                        numcheck = 1;
                    }
                }

                else if(randx == 3)
                {
                    if(randy == 1 && c1 == 0)
                    {
                            c1 = 2;
                        numcheck = 1;
                    }
                    else if(randy == 2 && c2 == 0)
                    {
                        c2 = 2;
                        numcheck = 1;
                    }
                    else if(randy == 3 && c3 == 0)
                    {
                        c3 = 2;
                        numcheck = 1;
                    }
                    else if(randy == 4 && c4 == 0)
                    {
                        c4 = 2;
                        numcheck = 1;
                    }
                }

                else if(randx == 4)
                {
                    if(randy == 1 && d1 == 0)
                    {
                        d1 = 2;
                        numcheck = 1;
                    }
                    else if(randy == 2 && d2 == 0)
                    {
                        d2 = 2;
                        numcheck = 1;
                    }
                    else if(randy == 3 && d3 == 0)
                    {
                        d3 = 2;
                        numcheck = 1;
                    }
                    else if(randy == 4 && d4 == 0)
                    {
                        d4 = 2;
                        numcheck = 1;
                    }
                }
                else if(a1 > 0 && a2 > 0 && a3 > 0 && a4 > 0 
                        && b1 > 0 && b2 > 0 && b3 > 0 && b4 > 0 
                        && c1 > 0 && c2 > 0 && c3 > 0 && c4 > 0 
                        && d1 > 0 && d2 > 0 && d3 > 0 && d4 > 0)
                {
                    numcheck = 1;
                }
            }
            quit = 1;
        }
    }   

    public Main() 
    {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {       
        super.paint(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

        RandomSpawn();

        g2d.setColor(Color.white);
        g2d.drawLine(0, 0, 500, 0);
        g2d.drawLine(0, 100, 500, 100);
        g2d.drawLine(0, 200, 500, 200);
        g2d.drawLine(0, 300, 500, 300);
        g2d.drawLine(0, 400, 500, 400);      

        g2d.drawLine(0, 0, 0, 500);
        g2d.drawLine(100, 0, 100, 500);
        g2d.drawLine(200, 0, 200, 500);
        g2d.drawLine(300, 0, 300, 500);
        g2d.drawLine(400, 0, 400, 500);

        Font myFont = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 75);
        g2d.setFont(myFont);

            if(a1 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(a1), 30, 75);
            if(a2 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(a2), 100 + 30, 75);
            if(a3 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(a3), 200 + 30, 75);
            if(a4 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(a4), 300 + 30, 75);
            if(b1> 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(b1), 30, 100 + 75);
            if(b2 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(b2), 100 + 30, 100 + 75);
            if(b3 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(b3), 200 + 30, 100 + 75);
            if(b4 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(b4), 300 + 30, 100 + 75);
            if(c1 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(c1), 30, 200 + 75);
            if(c2 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(c2), 100 + 30, 200 + 75);
            if(c3 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(c3), 200 + 30, 200 + 75);
            if(c4 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(c4), 300 + 30, 200 + 75);
            if(d1 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(d1), 30, 300 + 75);
            if(d2 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(d2), 100 + 30, 300 + 75);
            if(d3 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(d3), 200 + 30, 300 + 75);
            if(d4 > 0)
                g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(d4), 300 + 30, 300 + 75);

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();   
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) 
    {

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
    {

    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
    {

    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) 
    {

    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        if(e.getY() < 125)
        {
            a1 = 1;
        }
        if(e.getY() > 275)
        {
            a1 = 2;
        }
        if(e.getX() < 205 && e.getY() > 125 && e.getY() < 275)
        {
            a1 = 3;
        }
        if(e.getX() > 205 && e.getY() > 125 && e.getY() < 275)
        {
            a1 = 4;
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: After quickly running your code I can see that it gets stuck in the paint method in the two while loops, consider assessing your game logic .

Comment: How can it get stuck there though? I have the last else if statement to prevent that.

Comment: Oh, I got it! The value of randx and randy will never be anything but 1-4, so therefore, checking to see if they arn't is irrelevant. I deleted the last "else" and everything works smoothly.

Comment: Have you considered using the mouse motion listener make it more similar?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you mean?